# Simplify $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^ky^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}$

Tags: summation, arithmetic

EDIT:

It is known that 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}
$$

Therefore, is it also possible to simplify 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^ky^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}$$ into something similar to the infinite geometric series sum?

Comment: What, you mean like $1 + xy + x^2 y^3 + x^3 y^6 + \cdots$?

Answer (score 0):

In the case $x=1$, we have 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty y^{k(k+1)/2} = \frac{\Theta_2(0, y^{1/2})}{2 y^{1/8}}$$
for $0 < |y| < 1$,
where $\Theta_2$ is a Jacobi Theta function.

I do not know of a "closed-form" expression for general $x$, but it's certainly not going to be an elementary function.